# How to stop fopen from triggering warning when attempting to open an invalid/unreachable URI

Tags: php

I'm using fopen to generate a price feed.

```
if (($handle = fopen("http://feedurl", "r")) !== FALSE) {

}
```

Is there a way to stop this warning if the feed fails:

> **Warning**:  fopen() [function.fopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`@`](http://php.net/@) to suppress the warning:

```
if(($handle = @fopen("http://feedurl", "r")) !== FALSE){

}
```

This is suitable here *because* you are handling the error condition appropriately. Note that liberal use of the `@` sign, in general, to suppress errors and warnings is ill-advised.

Per the [manual entry for `fopen`](http://php.net/fopen):

> If the open fails, an error of level E_WARNING is generated. You may use @ to suppress this warning.

Comment: Thanks Mark that works great! I can't believe how quickly people respond to questions on stackoverflow!

Comment: It also removes all other output

Answer (score 1):

here is another possible solution

```
$file_name = "http://feedurl";
if (file_exists($file_name) === false) {
    return;
}
$handle = fopen($file_name, "r");
```

Answer (score -2):

Or you can use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
```

Comment: Why would you want to hide all warnings for all functions executed in that script?